# Question related to APNS

Tags: iphone

Whenever I get a pop-up through the iPhone OS for [APNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) testing
there are 2 conditions:

1. application is running
2. application is not running

If I click on the view button of the popup through the iPhone OS then 
which method is called if application is running?

If application is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way, it launches the application so you need to implement 'applicationDidFinishLaunching:' in your application delegate.

If your app is running and you receive a notification, then you need to implement 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification'.

Read "[Handling Remote Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4)" for more information.